# using the foreach loop in php - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to exclude the the email code from the foreach loop, At the moment the email success message displays 3 times. i have tried different combinations but cant get it to display only once...?

Any ideas..? thanks

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $posted = $_POST;
    $options = array('option-1' => __('Procedure: Suture Skin Wounds', 'appthemes'),
            'option-2' => __('Procedure: Cat castration', 'appthemes'),
            'option-3' => __('Procedure: Cat spay', 'appthemes')
    );

    foreach ($options as $option => $value) {

        if ($posted[$option] == "selected") {
            echo "<li class='error-list'>";
            echo "Please select an answer for:" . "  " . $value . " >  
     " . '<a  href="' . get_permalink(30) . '">Back to form</a>';
            echo "</li>";
        }// if == "selected"
        else/* if(isset($_POST['submit'])) */ {

            $adminemail = get_option('admin_email');

            $ToEmail = $adminemail;
            $EmailSubject = 'Skills Assessment Form';
            $mailheader = "From Leapfrog";
            $mailheader .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
            $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
            $MESSAGE_BODY = "Form:Small Animal\n";
            $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: " . $_POST["canname"] . "\n\n";
            $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n\n" . "Procedure: " . "Suture Skin Wounds: " . $_POST["option-1"];
            $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n\n" . "Procedure: " . "Cat castration: " . $_POST["option-2"];
            $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n\n" . "Procedure: " . "Cat spay: " . $_POST["option-3"];

            mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die("Failure");
            echo "Your skills assessment form has been Sent:" . "  " .
            '<a href="' . get_permalink(13) . '">Back to your Dashboard</a>';
            //echo '<a href="'.get_permalink(13).'">Dashboard</a>';
        }//else                                  
    }//foreach loop;      
}//if isset
```

Comment: You need to put in your real code.

Comment: your explanation doesn't really make sense. possibly the code would help.

Comment: I agree it looks rubbish...!

Comment: Please format your code. Otherwise nobody wants to read and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything inside the `foreach` loop: Displaying errors, mailing the message and showing the success message.

You need to move all that out of the `foreach` loop, for example by setting an empty `$errors` array before the loop and adding all error messages to that array.

Then, after the loop, you can check if the `$errors` array is still empty and mail and display your success message. If not, you display all errors.

Comment: thanks for your answer - yes I understand, whats the method for adding the errors to the $error array..?

Comment: @Ledgemonkey Instead of echoing out your errors in the loop, you just add the html string to the array: `$errors[] = 'the html you want to echo out later'` and after the loop you loop through `$errors` and echo out every element.